# Normals are flipped

Tags: c#, godot

I colored normals with negative `y` red and here's what I get:

[image]

Any idea why some normals are flipped?

Here's simplified version of my code that add vertices, triangles, normals, etc.

I'm playing around with Godot, so axes are are the following:

- Vertical is `y` axis, up is positive
- Horizontal is `x` axis, left is positive (left in image)
- Depth is `z` axis, forward is positive (up in image)

```
public static TerrainMesh GenerateMesh(float[,] heights, Color[,] colors) {
  int width = heights.GetLength(0);
  int height = heights.GetLength(1);
  float topLeftX = (width - 1) / 2f;
  float topLeftZ = (height - 1) / 2f;

  TerrainMesh mesh = new TerrainMesh(width, height);
  int vertexIndex = 0;

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      mesh.Vertices[vertexIndex] = new Vector3(topLeftX - x, heights[x, y], topLeftZ - y);
      mesh.Uvs[vertexIndex] = new Vector2(x / (float)width, y / (float)height);

      // rudimentary normals
      if (x != 0) {
        // PS! if I swap Vector3's in Cross, upper half of the map has flipped normals
        Vector3 normal = mesh.Vertices[vertexIndex].Cross(mesh.Vertices[vertexIndex - 1]).Normalized();
        mesh.Normals[vertexIndex] = normal;
      } else if (x == 1) {
        Vector3 normal = mesh.Vertices[vertexIndex - 1].Cross(mesh.Vertices[vertexIndex]).Normalized();
        mesh.Normals[vertexIndex - 1] = normal;
      }

      if (x < width - 1 && y < height - 1) {
        mesh.AddTriangle(vertexIndex, vertexIndex + width + 1, vertexIndex + width);
        mesh.AddTriangle(vertexIndex + width + 1, vertexIndex, vertexIndex + 1);
      }

      vertexIndex += 1;
    }
  }

  return mesh;
}
```

Comment: I also get some normals artifacts in the border where normals flip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of computing normals shown here is beyond "rudimentary" - it's just flat out wrong. What you're computing there in no way corresponds to a terrain normal.

It's taking two vectors from the origin to different vertices in your mesh - which don't always belong to the same mesh triangle, even - and computing a normal of the triangle they form with the origin. Naturally, when you cross the origin, this triangle - which has nothing to do with the triangles of the mesh you're drawing - flips over, resulting in the inverted normals you see for half your mesh.

Try something like this instead:

```
Vector3 GetNormal(int x, int y, float[,] heights, float stepSize = 1.0f) {
    float center = heights[x, y];

    float left  = x > 0                        ? heights[x-1, y], center;
    float right = x < heights.GetLength(0) - 1 ? heights[x+1, y], center;

    float bottom = y > 0                        ? heights[x, y-1], center;
    float top    = y < heights.GetLength(1) - 1 ? heights[x, y+1], center;

    return Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(left - right, 2 * stepSize, bottom - top)
}
```

The `stepSize` variable corresponds to how great a distance there is between adjacent cells of your heightmap grid. Smaller values will exaggerate the normals, while larger values will tend to pull the normals closer to vertical.